# asp,net using site.master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the css class attribute that has been present on the site.master page at run time and I cant really get any head way I have so far tired

```
mainContainer.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image('myImage.png')");
```

AND

```
mainContainer.Attributes.Add("class", "className");
```

BUT non of these let me change the css of the master file at run time. i am using asp.net using c#

this is the code on the master page

```
 <div class="main">

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) is element wich won't be existed in output html code. It only defines a region. You can try to change div with class "main". Just add runat="server" and id attributes and access from the code.

```
<div id="MainDiv" class="main" runat="server">
```

and then

```
MainDiv.Attributes.Add...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to partially load the master page in the other child pages like below...

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site1.Master" %>
```

Then in the page load of the child page..put

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HyperLink contact_menu = (HyperLink)Master.FindControl("contactmenu");
        contact_menu.CssClass = "current";
    }
```

Change as per your need..
Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

You first need find the control on the master page

```
Image img = Page.Master.FindControl( "layoutStyleSheet" ) as Image;
```

then add style to it

```
img.Attributes.Add("class", "className");
```